# Anyone have a link to a technical discussion of anything akin to the Facebook news feed system?

Tags: facebook

I'm looking for a presentation, PDF, blog post, or whitepaper discussing the technical details of how to filter down and display massive amounts of information for individual users in an intelligent (possibly machine learning) kind of way. I've had coworkers hear presentations on the Facebook news feed but I can't find anything published anywhere that goes into the dirty details. Searches seem to just turn up the controversy of the system. Maybe I'm not searching for the right keywords...

@AlexCuse I'm trying to build something similar to Facebook's system. I have large amounts of data and I need to filter it down to something manageable to present to the user. I cannot use another website due to the scale of what I've got to work at. Also I just want a technical discussion of how to implement it, not examples of people who have an implementation.

Comment: Did you get around to finding something relevant? I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something along the lines of distributed pub/sub with content based filtering? If so, you may want to look into [Siena](http://serl.cs.colorado.edu/~serl/dot/siena.html) and some of the associated papers such as [Design and Evaluation of a Wide-Area Event Notification Service](http://www.inf.unisi.ch/carzaniga/papers/crw_tocs01.pdf)